# Check with BeautifulSoup if a html page doesn't contain a certain string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know is possible look for a string in a html page with BeautifulSoup using `findAll` function. If the target is the BeautifulSoup site, for instance:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

print soup.findAll(text="python")
```

The result would be:

```
[u'python']
```

But how do I check to see if there wasn't any occurences? Is it possible to have a boolean result?

Comment: Check the length of the result will do? If there wasn't any, it would be an empty list?

Comment: You're right. I added an extended example to the question and makes sense.

Comment: This is checking if an element with that exact text exists. Not the same thing as html containing the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Empty lists are evaluated to `False` , so you can just use an if statement, eg:

```
if soup.findAll(text="python") :
```

Or if you want to be more explicit you could use `bool` and turn it to boolean

```
bool(soup.findAll(text="python"))
```

Also you can use a lambda in `find_all` to collect tags if `text` does not contain some string

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: "python" not in tag.text)
```

Or if you want to check if all `NavigableString`s in the `soup` don't contain a certain string use:

```
all("python" not in s for s in soup.strings)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `soup.find()` be more efficient than `soup.findAll()`?

Comment: @Stevoisiak I don't think so. `Tag.find()` (BeautifulSoup inherits find() from Tag) [calls `Tag.find_all()` internally](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup/blob/480367ce8c8a4d1ada3012a95f0b5c2cce4cf497/bs4/element.py#L1234), so calling fid() could actually be less efficient. (The source code I linked is of BS4v4.4.0, but it remains the same in BS4v4.8.1)